# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json

No me funciona mi JSON, no entiendo porque, ya que siempre ha funcionado con el mismo codigo

**JSON**

```
{
    "numero 1" : 10,
    "numero 2" : 10
}
```

**Codigo en python**

```
import json

dir = "C:/Users/Thiago Grillo/Desktop/pruebajson/data.json"

with open(dir) as content:
    data = json.loads(content.read())
    n1 = data.get("numero 1")
    n2 = data.get("numero 2")
    print(n1+n2)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Thiago Grillo\Desktop\pruebajson\Python.py", line 7, in <module>
    n1 = data.get("numero 1")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

No entiendo porque ahora no funciona, no he cambiado absolutamente nada esta vez ¿Que pasa?

Comment: Tratas de acceder a una posición en un archivo json, no?

Comment: Podrías imprimir `data` a ver que contiene ...

Comment: He ejecutado el código y no tengo problemas :/

Comment: Al imprimir data aparece esto: [{'numero 1': 10, 'numero 2': 10}]

Comment: Por eso!! Eso es lo que no entiendo, A mi siempre me funcionaba Christian

Comment: Reinicie mi editor de codigo (VS Code) y no ha funcionado igualmente

Comment: @Skeletoos57 algo raro puedes hacer `data = json.loads(content.read())[0]` y problema resuleto, pero me intriga como llegaste a eso

Comment: has actualizado algún módulo de python??

Comment: Christian ha funcionado!! Gracias!! Yo tampoco entiendo porque ahora no funciona pero muchas gracias igual!!

Comment: estas volviendo a escribir el archivo en algún lado??

Comment: Sabes lo que si es verdad? (no se si tendra que ver) el archivo .py NO esta en la misma ubicacion que el archivo JSON, pero supongo que no tiene nada que ver, para eso creo una variable dir donde pongo la direccion del JSON

Comment: poco tiene que ver eso, pero igual digo que es algo extraño, podrías hacer `data = json.loads(content.read())` y luego hacer `data = data[0] if type(data)==list else data` y así manejar los casos donde el resultado varié entre lista y diccionario. Aunque no sé que tan bien funcione

Comment: Edita tu archivo json y agrega un segundo json a la cola. Ahora `json.loads()` debería retornar una lista con **dos** diccionarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ya funciona**

SOLO ES MI PROBLEMA PARECE, pero segun los comentarios a todos les funciona, pero a mi no, pero si te llega a pasar, coloca esto:

```
data = json.loads(content.read())[0]
```

Dado que `data` es una lista debemos acceder a un elemento de esta lista para poder obtener el diccionario, por eso usamos la notación de corchetes para acceder al primer elemento de esta lista que en mi caso es el diccionario que quiero. Me ha funcionado ahora